# Why is the inclusion of this js affecting the nested divs in my jade layout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am creating an html page for node.js using jade. It works as I want but if I uncomment out the fifth line - with the javascript source location - the sphere div is no longer nested inside content wrapper but is at the same level as it.

Why is this? This is really confusing me. And yes you are right -  I don't really know what I am doing!

```
extends layout
block content
    div(id="contentwrapper", resize="true", keepalive="true" )      
        div(id="sphere")
            //script(src='/javascripts/draw.js')
        div(id="demo")
            |jQuery is not present. You must install jQuery in this folder for   the demo to work.
        form(action="")
            div(class="form-item",id="color",name="color",value="#123456")
            label(for="color")
            div(id="picker")
```

Comment: Have I got the indentation wrong?

Comment: Why are you adding the script file directly into your HTML sructure?  It would be better to add this at the bottom of the page.  Your indentation looks ok to me.  You can also use #sphere instead of div(id="sphere") to render divs with id's.